# Express static assets in sub folders work on localhost, not on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My static assets all work just fine when running my node/express app locally. When I deploy it to AWS elastic beanstalk however, the only assets that are available are the ones not nested past `public/assets/css`, `public/assets/js`, `public/assets/svg` etc.

If the file path is `public/assets/svg/flags/filename` it doesn't work on the deployed app, but does work on local host.

`public/assets/svg/filename` would work however.

this is how I set my static assets path:

```js
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

this has forced me to put all my css in the `public/assets/css` folder, all my svgs in my `public/assets/svg` folder, and so on. I can't create additional sub folders to organize things and it's extremely annoying.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do they _not_ work? Do the requests result in a 404 or is it something else? Are all your files committed in git? Do you have any `.gitignore` rules that might be preventing nested directories from being included?

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response and for cleaning up my question.  Yes they result in a 404, and I just checked my .gitignore and there's nothing about that public directory. I also just noticed that some files do seem to work when nested several directories deep. It seems random to me, since they always work on localhost but not on the deployed app.

Comment: I have a lot of rules but none that affect public, and the files are all on github where they get deployed via codepipeline to aws eb.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac for local dev? EB would run on a Linux system with a **case-sensitive** filesystem. Make sure all your paths match the case of your file and directory names.

Comment: I'm on mac. I checked all my paths and they're all lowercase. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help Phil.

Comment: Actually, the lowercase thing fixed my some of my svg files! I still have to keep my js files in my public/assets/js directory though, they can't be nested or I'll get a 404 on aws. Like I said, It's still working on my mac localhost.